# How is the Uplink Corporation catching me [ARC path]?

Tags: uplink

I rediscovered this old game in its iPad iteration, and got really engrossed in it over the past couple days.

- Grabbed the Uplink Agent List, sold it, and threw all of the hackers on the list in jail using the criminal database
- Hacked a bank, netting myself a cool million dollars
- Always using the level 4 log deleter when disconnecting

More to the point, I chose the ARC path. I took missions 2, 3, and 4 from Arunmor in order to abandon them, leaving Faith at 0.2 and Revolution at 3.0 on the day we planned to strike.

My plan was to break into 15 internal services machines; copy Revolution, and then speedrun through those machines afterwards, causing untold chaos. Instead, on the 14th machine, I was disavowed by Uplink. Why would this happen? I was clearing logs between each jump and using Monitor & Firewall bypasses. Is there some sort of time limit to run Revolution before Uplink automatically disavows you? Would keeping a closer eye on my motion sensor have helped?

Answer (score 1):

What did you get disavowed for?

I'm guessing you most likely got disavowed for doing the ARC path, since when you do it you get disavowed, which may be the reason.

If it said you got disavowed for hacking into an organization, it would say which, and in that case, you did not get disavowed for the ARC play-through, but you got disavowed for well... hacking into an organization.